# How to listen for a "finished" indication after moving the execution to another thread in Qt

Tags: qt, qthread

I have a non-GUI operation which I intend to perform in a worker thread. 
After some googling, I figured out a simple way to achieve this [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects)

In particular, the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` suits me fine. I have also taken care of not sub-classing QThread and instead subclassing QObject to create my worker object and then moving the thread affinity of this object to a newly created thread. (decribed in some detail [here](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Now my question:

I will begin queuing methods from my main thread (I imagine this happens under the hood using a QEventLoop, even though I have not set one up and even though I have not re-implemented `QThread::run()` or called `QThread::exec()`) 
I need to find out when my worker has finished processing. In other words, I need to know when the QEventLoop is empty. I thought I could use the signal finished() for this. But it does not appear to work.
Can someone throw some light on how to find out when a worker thread has finished execution?
If you need more info/code, just let me know.

Class Plugin is a subclass of QObject

```
Plugin::Plugin()
{
    m_workerThread = new QThread(this);
    m_workerThread->start(QThread::IdlePriority);
    m_worker = new DataWorker(this);
    connect(m_workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));    
    m_worker->moveToThread(m_workerThread);
}
```

...

```
Plugin::updateData()
{
....
if( true == QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "RunFProcToGetData", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, foo)))
            {
                qDebug() << "successfully invoked RunFProcToGetData";
            }
            if( true == QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "updateDataIntoDB", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QSqlDatabase, db),                                                Q_ARG(QString, foo)))
            {
                qDebug() << "successfully invoked updateDataIntoDB";
            }
....
}
```

In Dataworker class

```
Dataworker::RunProcToGetData(const QString &foo)
{
// invoke a program to get the Data
}


Dataworker::updateDataIntoDB(const QSqlDatabase& db, const QString &foo)
{
// Update database 
}
```

So when there are no more updateDataIntoDB and RunFProcToGetData left to process, I need a trigger

Comment: post some code i have no idea what you are saying

Comment: Does simply calling `quit()` in the thread cause the `terminated()` signal to be emitted?  Unless of course you want to keep the worker alive all the time, in which case you will have to create your own signal.

Comment: @cmannett85: I want the worker to be alive and have no issues in creating my own signal and emitting it. But how do I know when to call quit() in the thread? For that I should look inside the QEventLoop which gets automatically setup once the thread gets created. Did not find any API for that.

Comment: If you want your worker to stay alive then don't call `quit()`.

Comment: @cmannett85: Yes. I'm not calling quit(). But what I need now is an indication when my worker has no more methods to execute and probably has been put in "pending" state. Is there a way to get this info?

Comment: `m_worker = new DataWorker(this);`.Remove `this`.movetothread() will fail if the parent is set.

Comment: @UmNyobe: Can you elaborate a little on the implication of using 'new DataWorker(this)' ?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Actually without the change you suggested, I inserted qDebug() statements in my main thread and worker object (or rather the function which I expect to run in worker thread)  and found two separate thread IDs. So does'nt that mean that the thread affinity has indeed changed?

Comment: The doc says [it doesnt work](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#moveToThread). Besides, the Qt parenting system is used to so an object can automatically act on other objects (when it is deleted, when widgets are shown, etc...). So you have 1 thread which do `m_worker.foo();` while due to a slot another thread is doing `m_worker.bar` : race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-implement QThread::run(), your code is just fine. Default run() will execute the event loop, and will execute Dataworker slots that are queued (Qt:QueuedConnection). Loop executes infinitely, until you explicitly stop it with thread->quit().

I would recommend you to put some notification signals to the Dataworker class that you will emit from RunFProcToGetData(), updateDataIntoDB(), ... So that you can connect notify signal from the last invoked method in the updateData() to the desired slot (probably in the Plugin). That connection will also be queued (Qt:QueuedConnection is default if objects run in different threads).

That way you'll be notified when all the queued methods from updateData() finish execution. You can than call updateData() multiple times; the m_workerThread will either run queued Dataworker slots or be idle. Remember to stop the thread and wait for it to complete in the destructor of the Plugin:

```
Plugin::~Plugin() {
    ...
    m_workerThread_->quit();
    m_workerThread_->wait();
    ...
}
```